# make child divs display inline with 100% width and parent overflow scroll

Tags: jquery, html, carousel, css

I've tried all day and can't seem to get this to work.
Here is a fiddle so you can understand what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/P2BqP/
I am sure it can be done with no Java script, but i guess there is something i am missing here. 
So I want to make the child divs take the value of the parent's `min-width`, so I can be able to horizontally scroll left or right, without having the parent expand. 
The reason I am doing this is because I want a scalable carousel without having to have a set width for the parent and child elements. I would like it to be scalable no matter the screen size or if user maximizes window size.
Does this make sence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplified version, but should get you the general idea:

CSS:

```
#container {
    background-color:#CCC;
    min-width:50%;
    max-width:300%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: block;
}

#container div {
    border: 1px solid #006;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P2BqP/3/

Comment: that is pretty much what I need. how would I make the text not go in a break to a new row and not go into a continuous line?  http://jsfiddle.net/P2BqP/12/

Comment: not sure what you mean. add overflow:hidden to #container div

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I actually ended up doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/P2BqP/13/
I was trying to make a carousel that wraps the text inside the `child divs`. Seems like i was trying a wrong approach.