# Horizontal scroll of elements (100% width) inside parent element with percentage width value

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using Bootstrap3 for creating pages in my application.

Somewhere deep in a page I have the column (`col-md-6`), which width is calculated by percentage. My current goal is to fill that element with a set of child elements, respecting following rules:

1. height of each child element must be inherited from the parent element;
2. width of each child element must be equal to width of the parent element;
3. child elements must be placed horizontally;
4. parent element must have horizontal scroll to navigate thru elements.

If we use fixed values (in `px`), the task becomes pretty easy. Like here http://jsfiddle.net/vUEYG/

But I have no idea how to solve it with percentage values. I mean, ok I can add some wrapper element with width equal to N*100% (where `N` is the number of child elements). But then the question is how to set width of child elements to those 100%? :)

Could someone give an advice?

Thank you

Comment: Just found 2 related questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235016/horizontal-scroll-of-inline-block-element and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519813/make-child-divs-display-inline-with-100-width-and-parent-overflow-scroll

Comment: Will try them first.

Comment: In your fiddle you use a wrapper, is it the case with your real scenario as well? ... Did you solved it with any of the other 2 questions you found?

Comment: First linked question and exactly this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/krV27/5/) helped me to solve my problem. I will post more details on my morning.

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood your requirements, I believe you can use `flex-box` to achieve this.

Note that there is no bootstrap used to achieve this, just straight css. If interested, there is a rather thorough breakdown of `flex-box` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#mask {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

content {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}

content > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="mask">
  <content>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </content>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does width 200% work but if I use something like 3000px then it pushes the parent div wider?

Answer (score 1):

Since your JSFiddle is using img references in the class names.
Maybe this could solve your challenge

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

This is a different approach to what it looks like you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

With some jQuery code you can do everything based on the most external div width:

```js
var childElementsNum = $('#wrapper')[0].childElementCount;

var itemWidth = $('#containersimg').width()
var itemSize = $('#containersimg').width() + 10; //here we add the 5px margin to left and right

$('#wrapper').css("width", itemSize * childElementsNum + 'px');

$('.square').css("width", itemWidth + 'px');
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 110px;
}

#containersimg {
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 500px;
  height: 135px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.square {
  background-color: #00b;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="containersimg">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I really recommend you to use some plugin, I suggest Owl Carousel:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Answer (score 0):

To place elements horizontally you will need to add float: left; in te css for the specified element

I replaced the .square css that you put in the link

```
.square {
   background-color: #00b;
   float: left;
   height: 90px;
   width: 18%;
   margin: 1%;
}
```

width=18% for the content and margin=1% for each side

and it works the same way

You can create a column inside of another and set the bootstrap col-lg... property but probably you wont be able to use the horizontal scroll